# Why list comprehension doesn't work the same as code without comprehension?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, unique, list-comprehension

I tried to create a simple function to remove duplicates from the list.

```
x = [7, 7, 5, 6, 8, 9, 9, 0]
for n, i in enumerate(x):
  if i in x[n + 1:]:
    x.remove(i)
print(x)
```

**Output:**

```
[7, 5, 6, 8, 9, 0]
```

This code works fine as far as I know.

But when I'm trying to convert it in comprehension list form, I'm getting wrong output:

```
def unique_list(lst):
  return [lst.remove(i) for n, i in enumerate(lst) if i in lst[n + 1:]]

x = [7, 7, 5, 6, 8, 9, 9, 0]
print(unique_list(x))
```

**Output:**

```
[None, None]
```

So, the question is - why the output is different?

Comment: You're modifying list while you're iterating over it in both examples which is really bad practice. This code will work: `x1 = [i for i, j in zip(x, x[1:] + [None]) if i != j]`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove items from a list while iterating?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207406/how-to-remove-items-from-a-list-while-iterating)

Comment: @OlvinRoght in real world coding I'm not going that way. My interest in this case is theoretical.

Comment: Voting to close, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/1207461/2375855 . And your example function suffers from being very similar to simply `list(set(x))`. (Only similar, as this does not preserve order.)

Comment: You are returning the output of .remove(), which is always None.
The remove method changes the list, its not returning a changed list

Comment: @ojdo I'm trying to understand what's the difference between this to examples sees Python interpreter and why the output is different.

Comment: @QuantiMonati, difference is in logic. Examples aren't equal. In first example you're removing elements from list and return this list, in second example you're creating list which contains return of `list.remove()` which will alway be `None`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your two ways of writing the functionality of `set(x)` are not identical. While the first is using a side-effect of `x.remove(..)` to "return" your modified list in place, the second form returns a newly created list.

The elements of that list are formed by what is *returned* by the expression `lst.remove(i)`, which is `None` as Manuel already has pointed out in their answer.

You receive `[None, None]` because your code calls `lst.remove` 2 times. So your function `unique_list` could be called `count_duplicates`, just with a peculiar output format (with the length of a list of `None` encoding the result instead of a straightforward `int`).

Answer (score 3):

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
deleted = a.remove(1)
print(deleted)
# returns None
print(a)
# returns [2, 3]
```

.remove() changes the list in place and returns `None`